# How use vertical detection in ARKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

How can I insert a SCNScene with a vertical hold on ARKit? I can not do the detention and insert the object in a vertical position.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView?.delegate = self

    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView?.showsStatistics = true

    // Create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/tabellone.scn")

    sceneView?.debugOptions = [SCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView?.scene = scene!
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    configuration.planeDetection = .vertical
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView?.session.run(configuration)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an **appropriate vertical surface** for tracking. Wall with a solid color (with no distinguishable features on it) is very bad instance (you can see such a vertical surface on the left image). The most robust approach for tracking of a vertical surface is a **well-lit** brick wall, or a wall with pictures on it, or a wall with a distinguishable pattern, etc.

[image]

So the right image is quite good example for tracking and vertical plane detection.

If you want to explore how to place 3D object onto detected plane, look at Apple's [Handling 3D Interaction and UI Controls in AR](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/handling_3d_interaction_and_ui_controls_in_augmented_reality) project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It depends on what you wanna get. But a code itself is correct.

Comment: I want to select a vertical plane and insert the .scn object